# TinyMCE imagemanager doesn't work

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg, mcimagemanager

I have a problem with TinyMCE imagemanager
it works on Windows (WAMP) but on Ubuntu I am facing following issue

http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=146581Capturedu20130320192619.png

How can I solve it?